# Season Identification in SAS

Tags: sas, statistics, time-series, data-analysis, data-science

I have three years worth of monthly data showing concentrations of X chemical in a sample. The data shows seasonality as predicted. However, the seasons are not your regular summer/winter/etc. I am trying to find out how I can delineate the seasons in SAS. I am trying to break the year down to 2 main seasons (high vs low concentrations). So I need SAS to be able to identify where that break is between the two seasons (i.e., which months are in the high concentration season and which months are in the low concentration season). Any way to do that?

Comment: Post what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You will want to use `proc timeseries` to decompose the series and estimate the season. You can alternatively use `proc spectra,` but `proc timeseries` is much more comprehensive.

```
ods graphics on;

proc timeseries data=sashelp.air plots=(decomp sc sa cycles sic periodogram);
    id date interval=month;
    var air;
run;
```

The results clearly indicate a season of 12 in our example.

[image]